# AttributeError: 'SigSafeLogger' object has no attribute 'logger'

Tags: python, django, celery, backend, mixpanel

I'm trying to integrate mixpanel celery into my backend and keep getting the following error. Can someone help please?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/home/modalyst/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/home/modalyst/webapps/django/modalyst/modalyst/main2/views.py", line 3959, in item_manager_add
   et.run('New Item Created by Designer',{'user_id':11},token='REMOVED_MY_API_TOKEN')

 File "/home/modalyst/lib/python2.7/mixpanel/tasks.py", line 42, in run
   if l.logger.getEffectiveLevel() == logging.DEBUG:

AttributeError: 'SigSafeLogger' object has no attribute 'logger'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SigSafeLogger` objects have no attribute `logger`.

Try not attempting to access that attribute. If you are not doing it directly, stop passing `SigSafeLogger` objects to whatever code is raising this error.